# Play sound through JavaScript on an iPhone without interrupting the music being played

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

When running `audioElement.play()` in a browser (safari) on an iPhone. It stops the music being played.

Is it possible to keep the music playing and have the audio ran along side the music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio can be played along side music by using `AudioContext`. Link to docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext